# RandomForest: how to use a person_id and company_id attribute in machine learning

Tags: r, random-forest, overfitting

I'm trying to train a randomForest model in R in a 500k+ row dataset. So far so good, but now I'm trying to include factors person_id and company_id (non-unique) which both have a huge amount of levels (in the thousands, many more than R can handle).

There is an overlap between training and test set for these attributes of 40% and 70%, so I'm thinking these variables could be useful.

I'm trying to classify succes or not (0,1) and have therefore generated new features like frequency of the id's in training set and percentage of success per id in training set. I merged these attributes into the test set.

I replaced all the "new" ID's in the testSet by either 0's or 1's. After training with the new variables, it results in a huge overfit (due to the new unknown ID's).

Is there a way I could benefit from the attributes which I think could be valuable.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly. Is the problem simply that the two variables have many levels? Also, is person_id unique for each row? If so, it won't do much good as a predictor.

Comment: It's non unique. SO for example certain person_id's could be very successful (result in a classification of: 1). However, I know my final testset and using the person_id's as predictors (by creating new numeric attributes based on person_id) results in a huge overfit. Because the testset contains 65% new person_id's. So it makes sense that this is the result of an overfit. My question is: How can I still use these possibly interesting ID's? My first guess would be sampling in a way that my training set is sampled based on the overlap and 65% unknown ID's